# Pointers and cout address of a variable

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

I am trying to cout the address of the variable abc and the program just crash

```
int main()
{
    int *app;
    int abc = 2;
    *app=3;
    cout << *app << endl << &*app << endl << abc;
    cout << &abc;

}
```

However, if I remove the address variable int *app , then it will cout the address of abc

```
int main()
{
    int abc = 2;


    cout << &abc;

}
```

I have no idea why would the existence of another unrelated address variable would affect it. Please advise.

Comment: please specify "doesn't work"

Comment: What address does `app` hold when you `*app = 3`? Undefined.

Comment: app is not pointing to any valid memory address. you must be getting segmentation fault because of that in first case.

Comment: thanks everyone. I should have realized such an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
*app=3;
```

this will probably cause a **Segmentation Fault**, *Undefined Behavior*.

If you remove it, it makes sense to see the expected output.

Comment: ...and also here `cout << *app << endl << &*app`

Comment: Yes of course @bkVnet. Since `*app=3;` is doomed to be wrong, printing w.r.t. that will be problematic. Do you think I should include that in my answer?

Comment: No, i was just mentioning the obvious. You have addressed the point well.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?? This is undefined behavior.

```
int *app;  // pointer is not initialized.
int abc = 2;
*app=3;  // de-referencing an uninitialized pointer.  Bad.
```